# How to update an existing .po file with a newly generated .pot file?

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, poedit, po, cakephp-2.x

Cake version is 2.x. I have extracted all the texts inside `__` function with `./Console/cake i18n extract` command, moved the `default.pot` file into `app/Locale/[iso3]/LC_MESSAGES/default.po` and translated it to corresponding language. Everything is working fine.

After some time I have added some new functionality into the site and I need to add those messages into the `po` file. However if I use the same command it will create a new pot and I have to either manually merge them or replace with new po file and copy/paste the translations - both are too much manual work, because I have a few thousand lines of text.

Is there any way to tell cake update my `po` file adding only messages that does not exist in there ?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Download [PoEdit](https://poedit.net/download). It has an option to update your `PO` file from an existing `pot` file. From the menu go to `Catalog -> Update from POT file`.

So you will create your a new `POT` file and then update your `PO` file. PoEdit will update the `PO` file with the new values and I think it also removes any unnecessary ones.

***PS:*** It would be wise before making any move to keep a backup.

Comment: Because of your words using a backup ;) I would go a bit further and suggest using Git.